# When is a polyhedron uniquely determined by its projections?

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, polyhedra, combinatorial-geometry, polytopes

Let $P$ denote a polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^D$ defined by the intersection of $k$ halfspaces, so $P = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^D : Ax\le b\}$ for $A\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times D}$, $b\in\mathbb{R}^k$. For a subset of coordinates $S\subseteq\{1,\ldots, D\}$, let $P_S$ denote the projection of $P$ onto $\mathrm{span}(\{e_i : i\in S\})$. I want to know when $P$ is uniquely determined by projections of the form $P_S$. If enforcing that $P$ is bounded makes things simpler, that is fine as well.

For concreteness, I am interested in statements of the form "If $P$ is the intersection of $k$ halfspaces in $D$ dimensions, then it is uniquely determined by projections of the form $P_S$ for $|S|\le m$", where $m$ is something that depends on $k$ and $D$.

Klee's theorem seems relevant (see, e.g., https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15612/do-plane-projections-determine-a-convex-polytope) but it does not say anything about uniqueness.

Comment: Ah, so you're asking about *classes* of convex polyhedra distinguishable by sufficiently many projections? What kind of classes are you looking for?

Comment: @Magma Well the class I had in mind was the collection of convex polyhedra (or polytopes) defined by the intersection of $k$ halfspaces in $D$ dimensions. The example with boxes doesn't fit this but was just a basic thing I came up with to illustrate my question.

Comment: Your example with half-spaces in general position is uniquely determined by the *intersections* with the coordinate axes, not the projections onto them. The (orthogonal) projections of a half-space onto axis-aligned proper subspaces are always surjective and will not provide any information.

Comment: @Magma Ah yeah sorry, what I had in mind was linear separators restricted to the orthant $x\ge 0$, in which case the projections would determine the intersection points. I can delete the examples if it's making things unclear. I think my main question is still valid (maybe I should modify the question to only deal with polytopes), so I'm not sure why you're voting to close it.

Comment: It is still unclear what you are asking for. Please consider adding a formal, concise question statement that lets the reader easily identify what you expect to see in a complete answer.

Comment: @Magma Ok, I removed the ill-posed examples and added a more concrete form of what I'm interested in. I don't necessarily have a clear picture of what I want from a complete answer, I'm just interested in any results or ideas related to what I posted. I was under the impression that such open-ended inquiries are not prohibited on this forum.

Comment: I don't think even Klee's theorem holds for the limited set of projections that you have allowed.

Answer (score 2):

If $P$ is the intersection of $k > 0$ halfspaces in $D > 0$ dimensions, then it is not necessarily uniquely determined by all projections of the form $P_S$ for $|S| < D$. This still holds true even if $P$ is restricted to be bounded.

Counterexample for the unbounded case: Choose $k$ distinct unit vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ all of whose coordinates are positive. Let $$P := \bigcap_{i=1}^k\{x \in \mathbb R^d: \langle x, v_i\rangle \leq 1\}$$ be a convex polyhedron. Then $P_{|S|} = \mathbb R^{|S|}$ for all $S \subsetneq \{1, \ldots, D\}$. A different choice of $v_i$ changes $P$, but yields the same projections.

Counterexample for the bounded case: First, $k > D$ is required for $P$ to exist.
Let $P_0$ be the convex hull of $\{0, e_1, \ldots, e_D\}$, let $v$ be any vector in the interior of $P_0$. Then $P_v$, defined as the convex hull of $\{v, e_1, \ldots, e_D\}$, has the same projections as $P_0$. Both $P_v$ and $P_0$ are simplices definable as the intersection of $D+1 \leq k$ hyperplanes.